# reset permissions back to default

Tags: chmod

How can I reset permission to default according to the mask, so they will have permissions set as the file was just created

Example of what I want to achieve:
`umask` is set to 0022
so

```
touch file
mkdir directory
```

file's permissions now are `rw-r--r--`

directory's permissons now are `rwxr-xr-x`

```
chmod 777 file
chmod 777 directory
```

file's permissions now are `rwxrwxrwx`

directory's permissions now are `rwxrwxrwx`

is there a way to reset perms back to default so file will be `rw-r--r--` and directory `rwxr-xr-x` using `chmod`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using subtraction is only correct for some umask values - it's better to use `mode & ~umask`, like [in PSkocik's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249856/70524), or `chmod =rw` (or `chmod =rwx` for directories) which applies the umask as specified by the standard, [as noted by ilkkachu in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249845/reset-permissions-back-to-default/249850?noredirect=1#comment1222243_249850).

---

In some cases, you can just subtract the `umask` from `0666` for files and `0777` for directories to get default permissions:

```
$ printf "%04d\n" "$((0777 - $(umask)))"
0755
$ printf "%04d\n" "$((0666 - $(umask)))"
0644
```

Accordingly, you can apply `chmod`:

```
chmod $((0666 - $(umask))) file
chmod $((0777 - $(umask))) directory
```

In bash, you have to use `printf` to force the output in octal:

```
$ printf "%04d\n" "$((0777 - $(umask)))"
0493
$ printf "%04o\n" "$((0777 - $(umask)))"
0755
```

---

Another way would be to create a new file and directory, and use them as reference:

```
touch file2
mkdir directory2 
chmod --reference=directory2 directory
chmod --reference=file2 file
```

Comment: also I found something like `chmod =rwx file`, not sure what exactly it does but looks like it resets permissions to default too but only for directories

Comment: Note that Bash, unlike ZSH, treats values beginning with 0 as octal values. For these examples to work in Bash, the numbers need to be prefixed with `10#`. For example: `chmod $((10#0666 - 10#$(umask))) file`

Comment: The produces incorrect results for files if the umask has “1” anywhere (uncommon perhaps but still possible). umask isn’t subtracted.

Comment: @JohnKarahalis, as long as there's no carry, it doesn't matter if the numbers are taken as octal or decimal. E.g. 6 - 4 = 2 in either. 4 - 6 would differ, though. But like Stephen says, the umask shouldn't be subtracted but bitwise modified. So we need the numbers to be interpreted correctly. In Bash, Dash, and Ksh, `printf "%o\n" "$(( 0666 & ~$(umask) ))"` should work. Zsh needs `printf "%o\n" "$(( 8#0666 & ~8#$(umask) ))"`, but then that doesn't work in Dash.

Comment: `chmod =rwx file` also works, it sets the permissions to 0777 modified by the umask. See the sentences with "if *who* is not specified" in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/chmod.html

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, that's true if the umask is being bitwise modified. To be pedantic, though, even though 6 - 4 is the same in octal and decimal, as you note, 666 - 444 is not. Thus, `$((0666 - 0444))` in Bash is equal to decimal 146 but `$((10#0666 - 10#0444))` is equal to decimal 222. In any case, you may be right that bitwise is the way to go to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JohnKarahalis, well, it is in the sense that 666o - 444o = 222o, when all three numbers are in octal. Somehow, I first thought Zsh did just that, output in octal if the inputs are in octal, but of course it doesn't. But bitwise masking isn't just to avoid confusion, it's to deal with a case like 0600 masked with 0002. If you do the subtraction, you get 576 (octal to octal), or 598 (decimal to decimal). Neither is right, it should get left to just 0600.

Answer (score 9):

The masks are applied via bitwise `AND` with the `bitwise negated` mask so if you want to create your own final permission mode, you can do:

```
$((mode & ~umask))
```

You'll need to print that back in octal so that you can pass it to `chmod`:

```
$ chmod `printf '%o' $((0777 & ~$(umask)))` directory
$ chmod `printf '%o' $((0777 & ~0111 & ~$(umask)))` file
#^additional implicit mask of 0111 for files
```

where 0777 is the permission mode you want to apply the mask to (you can obtain it with `stat -c %a file` or `stat -c %a directory`).

You can echo the above to see what the process substitution will evaluate to (for an `umask` of `0022`, you will get `755` and `644`).

You could make a generic function out of it:

```
#takes a umask as first param and applies it to each folowing param (files)
maskMode(){
  local mask="$1" dmask mode a
  dmask="$((mask & ~0111))"; shift
  for a; do
    mode=0`stat -c "%a" "$a"`
    chmod `printf "%0.4o\n" $(($mode & ~mask))` "$a"
  done
}
```

For your particular use, chmod reference files are another option.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it recursively through the current directory -

```
chmod -R $((777 - `umask`)) .
chmod -R -x+X .
```

You can replace `` `umask` `` with `$(umask)`.

Comment: Backquotes, not single quotes

Comment: I don't think `chmod -R -x+X .` works. It did not seem to have any effect when I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

**Recursive files and directories**

For anyone looking to reset all files and directories recursively within a parent directory:

```shell
sudo find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod $((0666 - $(umask)))
sudo find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod $((0777 - $(umask)))
```

**Explanation**

The other answers showed how to reset individual files and directories (or apply one rule to both recursively) with `chmod -R $((0666 - $(umask)))` and `chmod -R $((0777 - $(umask)))` respectively. (Great answers, thanks!)

I then found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163294/changing-chmod-for-files-but-not-directories.) showing how to apply permissions selectively using find throughout the directory:

```shell
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

This will change files recursively, and therefore

```shell
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

will apply to directories.

Stringing these answers together provides the above solution. Note that this requires the GNU version of `find` and `xargs` for the `-print0`/`-0` options, respectively.

Hope it helps others!