# How to create a temporary file that has "normal" permissions?

Tags: shell, files, permissions, mktemp

In a build script I want to create a temporary file that has a unique generated name, then write some data to it, and then rename that file to its final name (the reason for this procedure is that I want the renaming to happen (mostly) atomic).

But if I use `mktemp`, the new file will have very restrictive permissions:

> Files are created u+rw, and directories u+rwx, minus umask
> restrictions.

... and these permissions will be preserved when the file is renamed. However, I want the resulting file to have "normal" permissions; that is, it should have the same permissions as files created by `touch` or by a shell redirection.

What is the recommended way to achieve this? Is there a (common) alternative to `mktemp`; or is there a simple and reliable way to change the file permissions to the normal `umask` permissions afterwards?

Comment: You can just run `chmod` on it, can't you? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249850

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reset permissions back to default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249845/reset-permissions-back-to-default)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: sorry for the late reaction. You are correct, resetting the permissions back to default is pretty much what I need! However the question you linked to doesn't mention the very elegant solution given by ilkkachu below, so I'm not sure if it's useful to mark this as a duplicate of that other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `chmod =rw "$file"` after creating the temp file. The [GNU man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) says:

> A combination of the letters `ugoa` controls which users' access to the file will be changed: [...] If none of these are given, the effect is as if (a) were given, but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.

So, `=rw` gives read-write permissions reduced by the umask, similar to passing `0666` as the permissions argument to `open()`, which is what e.g. `touch filename`, or `echo > filename` would do.

That's a [POSIX feature](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/chmod.html#tag_20_17_13), so other implementations should support it too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to get the desired permissions you want http://permissions-calculator.org/

### Manual

Create a script file that creates a new file, then changes its permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash

Filename=$1
Perms=$2

#Create a temp file
touch $Filename

#Change the file's permissions (Use your own desired permissions)
chmod $Perms $Filename
```

After making the script executable `chmod +x myscript.sh`, execute the script file like this `./myscript.sh tempfile 600`

### Using Umask (Don't Recommend)

you can temporarily change the default file permissions using `umask 600` for example.

To permanently change the default file permissions, edit your .bashrc file in your user's root directory.

`nano ~/.bashrc`

add `umask 600` to the bottom of the file.
Ofcourse, make sure to match your desired permissions.
Make sure you edit the correct user as well.

If this is for a build script, I would use the manual method instead of relying on umask. Especially if your build script will be used on different systems.

Comment: `umask` probably doesn't help with `mktemp`. At least the GNU version says "Files are created u+rw, and directories u+rwx, minus umask restrictions.", so you can't use the umask to get permissions for group and others

Comment: You are right, i included it just because they asked about it in the question. I updated the answer to reflect that ^^